# How to hide a button in Swift 4 programmatically

Tags: swift

How can I hide a `button` in Swift 4? I tried the `.isEnabled` and the `.isHidden` function but these two didn't work? Did I make something wrong is there another function necessary?

Thats's what I tried:

```
finishButton.isHidden = false

finishButton.isEnabled = false
```

I want, that the button is invisible.

Comment: finishButton.isHidden = true is correct way . Please control your code

Comment: What about setting `finishButton.isHidden` to **true** if you want to hide it?

Comment: @MartinR Oh yeah xD. That's my bad I'm sorry.

Comment: FYI - from the documentation for the `isHidden` property of `UIView`: *"Setting the value of this property to true hides the receiver and setting it to false shows the receiver."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not True** `finishButton.isHidden = false`

**True way is**    `finishButton.isHidden = true`